# Could not initialize the package information up date manager

Tags: apt

An unresolved problem occurred while initializing the package information. It says I have a bug against the update manager package with this error message:

```
E:Malformed line 58 in source list/etc/apt/sources.list (distribution parse)
```

Comment: Could you please add the content of /etc/apt/sources.list to your question?

Comment: Ok I am new to this help me out. What content?

Comment: /etc/apt/sources.list is a text file. You can read it in many ways, for instance with the text editor application. So launch text editor, open /etc/apt/sources.list and copy the text from the file into your question.

Comment: Open a terminal Ctrl-Alt-T and run the command `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`. Copy the output and paste in your question by [edit]ing your question. Not as screenshot, not as comments please. **;)**

Comment: ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-proposed restricted main multiverse universe
deb http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/precise steam
deb-src http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/precise steam

Comment: As I said, edit your question and add the output and don't use the comments for that

Answer (score 0):

There's a syntax error in your sources.list, so checking for package updates is failing. You should either open your sources.list file and correct the error, or you can just reset your sources by following the instructions outlined here: https://askubuntu.com/a/192388/470880

Edit - If you'd like help correcting the issue in your existing sources.list file, run the following and copy and paste the contents of your sources file here:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```